# Why doesn't Blender 2.83 load?

Tags: installation, versions

I have been waiting for 2.83 Blender, but I installed it and try to start it up it doesn't even load. All previous Blender versions worked fine.

What have you changed in  2.83 for this to happen?

Comment: Perhaps try the Portable (.zip) version? https://www.blender.org/download/  > **macOS, Linux, and other versions** > **Windows Portable (.zip)**.

Comment: Nope, still same issue. Nothing loads - EXE and then it just doesnt load

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem, the the 2.83 Windows installer is asking if I want to CHANGE, REPAIR or REMOVE Blender.